# C# Trouble with > "There is an error in XML document (2, 2)" i am not sure what the issue is

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I have an error (There is an error in XML document (2, 2).) I have been breaking my head over this. I cannot seem to pinpoint the error. I would really appreciate if a fresh set of eyes could help me.

```
    public GunPresenter()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.foo.com/handguns.xml");
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += OnDownloadStringCompleted;
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    }

    void OnDownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(args.Result);
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GunLibrary)); **//Error is here**
        GunLibrary = (GunLibrary)xml.Deserialize(reader);
```

---

handguns.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <HandgunLibrary xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <TypeOfGun>Handgun</TypeOfGun>
      <Guns>
        <Gun>
          <GunName>Ballester-Molina</GunName>
          <Type>Single Action</Type>
          <Caliber>.45ACP</Caliber>
          <Capacity>7 rounds</Capacity>
          <WeightUnloaded>1075 grams</WeightUnloaded>
          <Legth>216 mm</Legth>
          <CountryOrigin>Argentine</CountryOrigin>
          <PhotoFileName>http://foo.com/gunImages/ballester.png</PhotoFileName>
          <YearMade>1938-1953</YearMade>
        </Gun>
        <Gun>
          <GunName>Bersa Thunder 9</GunName>
          <Type>Double Action</Type>
          <Caliber>9x19mm Luger/.40S&amp;W</Caliber>
          <Capacity>17(9mm)/13(.40)</Capacity>
          <WeightUnloaded>870 grams</WeightUnloaded>
          <Legth>192 mm</Legth>
          <CountryOrigin>Argentine</CountryOrigin>
          <PhotoFileName>http://foo.com/gunImages/bersathunder9.png</PhotoFileName>
          <YearMade>1994-present</YearMade>
        </Gun>
        <Gun>
          <GunName>Bersa Thunder-mini</GunName>
          <Type>Double Action</Type>
          <Caliber>9x19mm Luger/.40S&amp;W</Caliber>
          <Capacity>13(9mm)/10(.40)</Capacity>
          <WeightUnloaded>765 grams</WeightUnloaded>
          <Legth>165 mm</Legth>
          <CountryOrigin>Argentine</CountryOrigin>
          <PhotoFileName>http://foo.com/gunImages/bersathundermini.png</PhotoFileName>
          <YearMade>1994-present</YearMade>
        </Gun>
        <Gun>
          <GunName>Bersa Thunder Ultra Compact</GunName>
          <Type>Double Action</Type>
          <Caliber>.45ACP</Caliber>
          <Capacity>7</Capacity>
          <WeightUnloaded>780 grams</WeightUnloaded>
          <Legth>173 mm</Legth>
          <CountryOrigin>Argentine</CountryOrigin>
          <PhotoFileName>http://foo.com/gunImages/bersathunderultracompact.png</PhotoFileName>
          <YearMade>1994-present</YearMade>
        </Gun>
        <Gun>
          <GunName>Bersa Thunder-380</GunName>
          <Type>Double Action</Type>
          <Caliber>.380ACP/.32ACP</Caliber>
          <Capacity>7(9mm)/9(7.65mm)</Capacity>
          <WeightUnloaded>560 grams</WeightUnloaded>
          <Legth>168 mm</Legth>
          <CountryOrigin>Argentine</CountryOrigin>
          <PhotoFileName>http://foo.com/gunImages/bersathunder-380.png</PhotoFileName>
          <YearMade>1995-present</YearMade>
        </Gun>
      </Guns>
    </HandgunLibrary>
```

//Complete

---

GunLibrary.cs

```
      using System;
      using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
      using System.ComponentModel;
      using System.Xml.Serialization;

      namespace HandgunLibrary
      {

public class GunLibrary : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    string typeOfGun;
    ObservableCollection<Guns> guns = new ObservableCollection<Guns>();


    public string TypeOfGun
    {
        set
        {
            if (typeOfGun != value)
            {
                typeOfGun = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TypeOfGun");
            }
        }

        get
        {
            return typeOfGun;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Guns> Guns
    {
        set
        {
            if (guns != value)
            {
                guns = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Guns");
            }
        }

        get
        {
            return guns;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propChanged)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propChanged));
        }
    }
}
```

}

---

Guns.cs

```
    public string GunName
    {
        set
        {
            if (gunName != value)
            {
                gunName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("GunName");
            }
        }

        get
        {
            return gunName;
        }
    }
```

//shortened

Comment: You 'shortened' the XML? It doesn't look like valid XML at all. Better include it verbatim.

Comment: You posted incomplete, invalid XML, and want us to help solve a problem with your XML? The only problems I can see is it's incomplete and invalid. Please edit your post and post a complete (doesn't have to be huge) snippet of the XML, or it's pretty much impossible to help you see what's wrong with it. (While you're editing, you might take the time to format your XML and code as well, so it's indented properly and easier to read.)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably post your full XML, but I have a feeling it is a Byte Order Mark (BOM) issue. Visual Studio doesn't always do the right thing with BOMs. Copy and paste the XML into another editor and save it. Notepad, Notepad++, etc. Below is a post with some more information on the issue.

http://blog.fourthwoods.com/2011/07/11/removing-the-byte-order-mark-inserted-in-source-files-by-visual-studio/

Erick

Comment: Thanks for the link but after doing what you said, i still have the same bug. Thanks